# Fubini's Theorem for Stochastic Integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Probably a bit trivial, but I was curious about the validity of interchanging the following integrals (where $W_t$ is Brownian Motion):

$\mathbb{E}[\int^{t}_{0} W^2_s ds] =? \int^{t}_{0} \mathbb{E}[W^2_s] ds$

In context, we know that $\mathbb{E}[\int^{t}_{0} W_s dW_s]^2 = \mathbb{E}[\int^{t}_{0} W^2_s ds]$

I just wanted to verify that its valid to make the jump that the above is equal to $\int^{t}_{0} s ds = \frac{1}{2}s^2$, since $\mathbb{E}[W^2_s] = s$ with Brownian Motion.

Comment: Just a minor comment on notation - the variable used in the integrand shouldn't also be used in the limits. e.g. write $\displaystyle \int_0^t s\,\mathsf ds$ instead.

Comment: Agreed, thanks! I made the edits.

Comment: In your equation with the question mark, those are not stochastic integrals and Fubini's theorem applies directly.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thanks. The fact that the integrand is stochastic adds no complications? Since the Isometry shows that the double integral is finite, Fubini holds?

Comment: @measure Reading the title of your question makes one think if you want to know whether $E[\int_0^tW_s\, dW_s] = \int_0^tE[W_s]\, dW_s$ holds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fubini's theorem on $[0,t]\times\Omega$ gives
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int^{t}_{0} W^2_s\, ds\right] 
=\int_\Omega \int^t_0 W_s^2(\omega)\,ds\,\mathbb{P}(d\omega)
=\int^t_0\int_\Omega  W_s^2(\omega)\,\mathbb{P}(d\omega)\,ds
= \int^{t}_{0} \mathbb{E}[W^2_s]\, ds.$$

Comment: Hi Byron, i used your answer for answering a (flawed) question ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392027/expectation-of-int-0t-w-s2-dw-s-integral-of-square-of-brownian-wrt-to-bro). Hopefully it has been answered.