# expectation of $\int_0^t W_s^2 dW_s $ (integral of square of brownian wrt to brownian)

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Looking for answers on the site I came across this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100345/stochastic-integral/100356#100356) with 3 upvotes where I am having trouble to understand an integral. Having not enough reputation (SE requires 50 reputation at least and I did not have access to chat until after editing) I cannot comment the post and ask [Sasha, the answerer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11069/sasha) for clarification.

> The said user stated: If $X := \int_1^2 W_s^2 \, dW_s$ then $E[X]=0$ where $W_s$ is a Brownian motion.

Yet I cannot understand how he came to this conclusion.

I followed the next steps and started from a more general question starting with $X=\int_0^t W_s^2dW_s$ :
1)Ito's isometry tells me that :$$ E\left[ \left(\int_0^t W_s \, dW_s \right)^2 \right] = E \left[\int_0^t W_s^2 \, ds \right]$$

2) Fubini's theorem (if I did unsterdand correctly from this [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1351404/468996) by [Byron Schmuland](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/940/byron-schmuland)) that i have: $$ E \left[\int_0^t W_s^2 \, ds \right] = \int_0^t E[W_s^2] \, ds = \int_0^t s \, ds = \frac{t^2}{2}$$

3) applying this to the particular case i would end up with this primitive evaluated in the following bounds : $$\left[\frac{s^2}{2}\right]^2_1=1.5$$

Which is different than $E[X] =0$

I cannot see what I am doing wrong.
On the form on the question are the \left \right brackets necessary for readability?

Comment: What you are doing is to calculate $\mathbb{E}(X^{\color{red}{2}})$. Itô's isometry allows you to compute $\mathbb{E}(X^{\color{red}{2}})$; you are interested in $\mathbb{E}(X)$!

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out! I will redo the maths and editing

Comment: Asking the OP in a comment to their answer was not an option because? (You did not even signalled them you were discussing the merits of their answer elsewhere, so much for courtesy.)

Comment: The site tells me i need 50 reputation to comment a post. Also the user Sasha (the one who came with the answer) did seem to come sporadically on the site when i looked at the frequency of his answers and questions. (1 every ~ month) and did not want to bother him for a 4 year old answer. And i am also unaware on the best practices of the site. The introducing tour doesn't tell you every step and etiquette.
 When writing any doc, I do put references but i do not send a notice to the author. I assumed it was the same here. Sorry if I was wrong.

Comment: I do not know the world you live in but in mine, whether on the internet or elsewhere, mathematics being involved or not, to discuss someone's actions/views/writings behind their back is problematic, to say the least. Re the specifics of the case at hand, when I look at Sasha's profile, I read "Last seen yesterday". So much for "sporadically". Re the limits your very low rep puts on the actions you can take, what I would be more interested in would be the next step of your reasoning: yes, your rep is extremely low, yes, this prevents you to perform tasks that asking your question here ...

Comment: ...  would require, and... **and what?** If you being unable to post a comment was a problem to you, you would have found a way, right? Say, by asking some other user to signal your post by posting a comment to Sasha's answer. But you did not. So, sorry but the limitations your very low rep entails are surely not the heart of the matter here. By the by, I now see that you *justify* this course of action so, please, make up your mind: deliberate choice or constraint due to the system?

Comment: @Did I politely invite you to criticize my behaviour / mistakes in the chat (e.g. C.R.U.D.E where I found you or a private one). But this debate is irrelevant to the current answer or the comment section and has its place in the _meta_ (again from my understanding of the mechanics of the site).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63741/discussion-between-randowmalk-and-did).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is to calculate $\mathbb{E}(X^{\color{red}{2}})$. Itô's isometry allows you to compute $\mathbb{E}(X^{\color{red}{2}})$; you are interested in $\mathbb{E}(X)$!

It is well-known the stochastic integral $$\int_0^t H_s \, dW_s$$ has expectation zero for **any** (nicely measurable) function $H$ such that $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t H_s^2 \, ds \right)<\infty$$ for any $t \geq 0$. To prove this, recall that

$$M_t := \int_0^t H_s \, dW_s$$

is a martingale which implies that $$\mathbb{E}(M_t)= \mathbb{E}(M_0)=0, \qquad t \geq 0$$ since martingales have constant expectation.

Comment: thanks for showing me how to edit, but why did you delete the equality and replace with :=? Because the integral is random and i can't put a strong equality?

Comment: @RandowMalk What do you mean by "strong inequality"? For me ":=" reads as "defined as"